# Recurring Google cookie interferes with search

Tags: firefox, cookies

Using Firefox on my computer at work, Google insists on using the old UI and behaviour ( see https://s1.areyoucereal.com/G5qae.jpg )

If I delete the NID cookie from .google.com, I get the new UI and behaviour ( see https://s1.areyoucereal.com/8M3XD.jpg ) for a while, then after some time (sometimes seconds, sometimes minutes) the undesirable behaviour recurs until I delete the cookie again.  Lather, rinse, repeat...

The problem is not just cosmetic.  The "old" site breaks user scripts and extensions that I use.

My home machine does not suffer from this problem, even though the NID cookie is present.

I have "safe browsing" turned off on both.

Comment: You network at work might have transparent proxy that somehow modifying http headers. Try to host somewhere outside a simple script that show CGI environment variables and compare this info between home and work. Check also that SSL certificate is really belong to google, since at work it possibly set SSL filter that substitute google's certificate with own to be able to decrypt and filter SSL traffic

Comment: I am pretty sure they don't (according to a friend of mine who works in the IT dept).

Comment: Besides, I played around with an empty FF profile with a couple of minutes and it does not seem to happen.

Comment: Then probably one of your addons replacing headers. Try to create another new profile in firefox without any plugins and check if it still behave the same way. AFAIK, usually Google switching to an old interface when user-agent string were changed or they think u using outdated version of browser

Comment: Currently Autopager is my prime suspect.  Disabling it seems to fix the issue (for now), but I am running it at home as well without problems.  Checking the rules will be a pain, since there are dozens of them...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the autopager rules for google sites.  Apparently google didn't like the requests.